# Single word covering "conclusions" and "implications"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a PhD defence ahead and trying different ways to improve my presentation. I will be expected to present **conclusions** (long and hard to follow sentences on a slide) and **implications** (to show that my work has an impact for the field/current practice).

My idea is to combine these two, meaning that I will present conclusions and implications together. Is there a single word for "**conlusions-implications**"?

Comment: I'd say "implications" refers to a subset of "conclusions" in your context anyway, so you could just drop the word completely if you *need* a single-word title for the final section of your presentation. Bear in mind that it's only your personal opinion / conclusion that the implications of your presentation ***have an impact on the field***. Your audience may infer their own completely different implications (such as "This guy is well out of his depth!", for all I know. :)

Comment: If your examiners expect you to present **conclusions** and **implications** then present them with **conclusions** and **implications**.  Trying to get smart, in the way you propose, at this end of your 3(?)-year search for a PhD will not win you any extra credit and there is a small chance that it will confuse your examiners.  Do you feel that lucky?

Comment: The only reason I can see to combine the two is to attempt to cover up a perceived flaw:  maybe you can’t decide what are conclusions and what are implications. Or may not enough of one or the other.  I’d sort that out and then follow the template.

Comment: "Long and hard to follow sentences on a slide" are yours for the fixing. Slides are not the place for the wording of your conclusions, but anchors for the audience to stare at while you expand and expound on the telegraph text. If you need to differentiate between conclusions and implications, one is a direct summation of your research, while the other is indirect—answering such questions as "So What?" and "Where do we go from here?".

Comment: Excellent question for your advisor. Not likely to get a relevant answer here.

Comment: *Implication* is an odd word to use for what you have in mind, because it normally stands for something that has not been made explicit; once you make the implications explicit, they cease to be implications. FumbleFingers is thus right that what you call implications are just conclusions, albeit of a different kind from other conclusions. If the word *implication* has some special meaning in your field (or at your institution), then you should seek advice on how to use it (or what the hypernym for it and *conclusion* is) from your advisor, as suggested by jimm101, rather than here.

Comment: *[Implications](https://www.assemblymade.com/2021/03/what-is-the-implication-section-of-a-research-paper/)* seems a common term in this context. They are normally things that aren't direct conclusions relating to the subject of the study, but things inferred from the results for public policy or subsequent research. There should be a clear distinction between what your study actually proves, and what hypothetical implications might follow e.g. what the public policy effects are of a study, or how it might direct future research. If you don't know what your study proves, you're in trouble.

Comment: @StuartF But as FumbleFingers said, implications can be part of conclusions. E.g. "We conclude that if global warming isn't arrested, the implications are dire."